# Control de flujo "if" en Liquid - Jekyll con símbolo "&"

Tags: condiciones, yaml, liquid

Estoy maquetando un menú de listas desplegables con Jekyll y liquid. Implementé un control de flujo con la condición "if" para que agregue la propiedad "checked" a los inputs que coincidan con la categoría del artículo. Así aparece desplegado en el artículo correspondiente y se le puede hacer un mejor seguimiento a la información.. por UX. Aquí dejo el código de ejemplo:

`<input id="accordion{{ forloop.index }}" type="checkbox" {% if cat contains page.category %} checked {% endif %} />`

La variable "cat" la asigno desde una línea anterior. Todo funciona muy bien. Sin embargo, me sucede lo siguiente:

**Cuando el resultado de las variables incluyen el símbolo &, la condición "if" no funciona.** Por ejemplo: si cat = "Advanced tips & tricks" y page.category = "Advanced tips & tricks", **no agrega la propiedad checked, aunque cumple la condición**.

Ya he probado lo siguiente: he utilizado 2 códigos exadecimales diferentes; he probado escribiendo el símbolo & directamente en ambas partes; encierro toda la variable entre comillas en los datos de origen. Y por supuesto, siempre hago los cambios en las fuentes de las 2 variables.

Ya no sé qué más probar para que cuando el resultado de la variable tenga el símbolo & la condición funcione.

Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Después de buscar diferentes maneras, lo único que tenía que hacer era utilizar la escritura del símbolo ampersand en HTML, y teniendo en cuenta que el filtro también es "case sensitive" en la anotación. El símbolo que utilicé es funcionó es el siguiente:

```
&#38;
```